# Setup DNS shortcut with BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, alias, shortcut

I need to setup an internal shortcut for DeployStudioPC in BIND to point the alias "deploystudiopc" to an IP address. I can't see how to set that up. I can add it to one of my internal zones, but then it would be a subdomain.

How do I setup one word aliases for ip addresses?

Answer (score 2):

What means "shortcut" ? Is it an alias in DNS terminology ? In this case, I don't know why you couldn't add an alias to an other machine (or an address with a A record), in your domain.
Just put **deploystudiopc.domain.tld. A 1.2.3.4** (without domain if the ORIGIN is defined)
or **deploystudiopc.domain.tld. CNAME othermachine.domain.tld**

Comment: I guess I don't know what to call it. The docs say to setup an alias for "deploystudiopc" to point to an address, but I don't know how to do that without putting it in a domain. 

Kinda like the "shortcuts" that OpenDNS offers. For example, you could set up "yahoo" to go to the http://www.yahoo.com/

Comment: The question is : this "shortcut" is mandatory for one or multiple machines ?
If the answer is one machine : add the name and IP in /etc/hosts (equivalent exists in Windows too)
If you have multiple machines, put it in a domain which is available only locally, and limit it to the machines which need "shortcut".

Comment: Every resolver will have a default domain. Go to a machine, open up a command prompt and type 

ping xxx

The output will show it pinging xxx.somedomain.com which tells you that you need to add your alias A record as a subdomain of somedomain.com